Assigning permissions based on resource groups using bicep - works on subscription
I have got the code below working, it assigns RBAC roles on object ID's at the subscription level, the code works perfectly well as it gives me a centralised way to manage roles, however the issue is that our subscription is quite broad and consists of different teams. I wouldn't want to grant a group contributor on a subscription for example as it gives them access to resources owned by another team.
I am trying to rewrite the code such that it works at the resource group level, whilst maintaining the same functionality.
Main.bicep
param principalID string
param principalType string
param roleIDs array
targetScope = 'subscription'

resource roleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-04-01-preview' = [for (roleID,i) in roleIDs: {
  name: guid(subscription().id, principalID, roleID)
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: 'providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/${roleID}'
    principalId: principalID
    principalType: principalType
  }
}]

auth_roleassignment_sub.module.bicep
param principalID string
param principalType string
param roleIDs array
targetScope = 'subscription'

resource roleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-04-01-preview' = [for (roleID,i) in roleIDs: {
  name: guid(subscription().id, principalID, roleID)
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: 'providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/${roleID}'
    principalId: principalID
    principalType: principalType
  }
}]

var_roleAssignmentInfo_module.bicep
param assignment array
targetScope = 'subscription'

module RBACAssignments './auth_roleassignment_sub.module.bicep' = [for roleAssignmentInfo in array(assignment) : {
  name: 'RBACAssignmentModule${roleAssignmentInfo.principalID}'
  scope: subscription()
  params:{
    principalID: roleAssignmentInfo.principalID
    principalType: roleAssignmentInfo.principalType
    roleIDs: roleAssignmentInfo.RoleIDs
  }
}]

The parameter file is roles.json
In its current format, it will assign the following roles to the group for example

Contributor
Attestation Reader
Key Vault Administrator



{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "roleAssignmentInfo":{
      "value":{
        "assignments":[
          {
            "principalID": "xxx",
            "principalType": "Group",
            "roleIDs": [
                "b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c",
                "00482a5a-887f-4fb3-b363-3b7fe8e74483",
                "fd1bd22b-8476-40bc-a0bc-69b95687b9f3" 
            ]
          },

          {
            "principalID": "xxx", 
            "principalType": "ServicePrincipal",
            "roleIDs": [
               "b86a8fe4-44ce-4948-aee5-eccb2c155cd7"
            ]
          }
          ]
          }
      }
    }
}





Rewrite the code such that it works at the resource group level, whilst maintaining the same functionality.

To rewrite the code for same functionality by changing scope to a resource group level, you need to change targetscope as resourceGroup as shown below and also add the resourceGroupName in the code to achieve the deployment in a specific resourcegroup.
The other module codes are no more required when you are deploying at a resource group level. Roles.json will be remained same as usual.
Modified bicep code:
param principalID string
param principalType string = 'ServicePrincipal'
param roleIDs string = 'b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c'
param resourceGroupName string

targetScope = 'resourceGroup'

resource roleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-04-01-preview' = {
  name: guid(resourceGroupName, '/', principalID, '/', roleIDs)
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments', roleIDs)
    principalId: principalID
    principalType: principalType
  }
}

Deployment succeeded:


